# How to hide a tag from a download page of Easy Digital Downloads

Tags: wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I created a function to redirect all the products with the tag 'ABC' to a different page (for logged-out users only).

`is_singular('download') && has_term(array('ABC'), 'download_tag')`

The problem is that logged-in users can still access the page and see the 'ABC' tag in the tags list.

What's the function that I can add to the functions.php file that will only hide the ABC tag specifically?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into [`get_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_object_terms/) to filter terms before they are displayed. Here's an example:

```
function custom_hide_terms( $terms, $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        // note that we are filtering by the term slug, not the term name,
        // so be careful with "ABC" versus "abc"
        $exclude = array( 'ABC' );

        // Loop through terms and remove ABC
        if ( $terms ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                if (is_object($term) && in_array( $term->slug, $exclude ) ) {
                    unset( $terms[$key] );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}

add_filter( 'get_object_terms', 'custom_hide_terms', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you it working great! couple of questions: 1. is there a way to only execute it on the downloads pages? I tried `is_singular('download')` but it didn't work.

Comment: Second, why did you use the `get_object_terms` filter and not `get_the_tags` for example?

Comment: @idomskt You can use `is_page( 'download' )` to check for the specific page.

Comment: @idomskt `get_the_tags` will work well if you know the specific post_id (which in this case, it sounds like you do) or if you use it within the WordPress Loop.  For more general purposes, `get_object_terms` is a better fit.

Comment: Kevin, unfortunately, the code is removing the tag from the backend as well, and therefore, it doesn't redirect the visitors. The code completely removes the tag from the product, and I'm only looking for a way to hide it on the front end from the printed list. Is there a way to keep the tag but not to display it? Thank you

Comment: @idomskt I added a conditional to the code above. It checks if the page is the admin dashboard before removing it.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you Kevin, but not yet. It does work locally, but when I push it to the live site, it still shows the tag for non-admins as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: @idomskt, there may be an ajax call that is impacting !is_admin().  To check for the frontend only, try changing "!is_admin()" to "wp_using_themes()"

Comment: It didn't work, so weird. Thank you very much for trying Kevin. You helped immensely.